# Typescript and WebRTC, 'createDataChannel' does not exist on type 'RTCPeerConnection'

Tags: typescript, webrtc

I'm experimenting with WebRTC and typescript, because typescript is awesome and webrtc is even awesomer... I'm doing this in the context of Angular 6 using VS Code.

It does not seem like a match made in heaven (probably due to me not understanding some integral part of either one).

I've had a hard time finding any examples of people using typescript for webrtc but when I started to try to translate a plain javascript example I noted that the methods and properties seemed to be recognized in Visual Studio Code at least. But I did not get far.

Below you can see me trying to translate a simple example to typescript.

```
createConnection ()
{       
    // window.localConnection = localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
    console.log(this.sendChannel);

    // sendChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel');
    var sendChannel = this.localConnection.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel');
    console.log(this.sendChannel);

    // localConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
    //   onIceCandidate(localConnection, e);
    // };
    // sendChannel.onopen = onSendChannelStateChange;
    // sendChannel.onclose = onSendChannelStateChange;

    // window.remoteConnection = remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    // console.log('Created remote peer connection object remoteConnection');

    // remoteConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
    //   onIceCandidate(remoteConnection, e);
    // };
    // remoteConnection.ondatachannel = receiveChannelCallback;

    // localConnection.createOffer().then(
    //   gotDescription1,
    //   onCreateSessionDescriptionError
    // );
    // startButton.disabled = true;
    // closeButton.disabled = false;
  }
```

On the definition of the sendChannel I get this error:

> src/app/app.component.ts(48,44): error TS2339: Property 'createDataChannel' does not exist on type 'RTCPeerConnection'.

The console log for the first log is:

> RTCPeerConnection { localDescription: null, currentLocalDescription: null, pendingLocalDescription: null, remoteDescription: null, currentRemoteDescription: null, pendingRemoteDescription: null, signalingState: "stable", canTrickleIceCandidates: null, iceGatheringState: "new", iceConnectionState: "new" }

and null for the second logging.

Appreciate any tips or hints as to why Im getting this error and how to fix it.

**Update**: added git repositoryng se that reporoduces problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/wokawaka/typescriptwebrtctest
npm install
ng serve --open
```

Comment: what browser? Edge does not support RTCDataChannel for example.

Comment: I get the error in VS Code, but using Firefox (latest version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like TypeScript 3.0.0 and newer have the declaration of `createDataChannel` but older versions do not.  Try upgrading TypeScript.  There is also the [@types/webrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webrtc) package, which may have newer declarations before they make it into the TypeScript standard library.

Comment: Added @types/webrtc but that did not help. I'll try upgrading.

Comment: I am using Typescript 3.0.3, have been the whole time.

Comment: I've also added adapter.js to the page, but no change.

Comment: Then I don't know what's going on.  If you publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you, I will mess with it.

Comment: Added git repo that reproduces the error to original question. Just redid those three steps listed and I get the 'createDataChannel' does not exist error. And thank you for your time :)

Comment: That repository [is using TypeScript 2.7.2](https://github.com/wokawaka/typescriptwebrtctest/blob/c03071d850cc8a5fcf1f16b694c90bdf650a301a/package.json#L32), hence the problem.  If you are stuck on a TypeScript version older than 3.0.0 because of Angular, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52414387).

Comment: Oh, Im unused to vs code and it said it was using 3.0.3 in the taskbar of the program som I assumed that was what was being used. Thank you!