# Up-to-date typings (like lib.dom.d.ts) for older TypeScript compiler

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 6 forces the maximum TypeScript version to be 2.9.2.

However, due to an outdated `lib.dom.d.ts` in this TS version, I'd like to use `lib.dom.d.ts` from TypeScript 3.0.3 which resolves issues I'm facing right now.

Is it possible to use `lib.dom.d.ts` from TS 3.0.3 in a TS 2.9.2 project without messing up with `node_modules` (manually replacing files there)?

Or as an option, are there `@types` packages containing up-to-date `lib.dom.d.ts` designed specifically for using with older than latest TS compiler?

Comment: What about going to that specific definition file and replace it with the newer version without pumping the whole TypeScript version?

Comment: why not use typescript 3.0.3?

Comment: @rhavelka: Because you get: `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 3.0.3 was found instead.`

Comment: @Microsmsm: Do you mean to do so in `node_modules`? Yes, this is the last resort, I'm just looking for any other maintenance-friendly options TS might have.

Comment: did you try `"lib": ["es2017", "dom"]` at `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Microsmsm: Sure. The issue is that IndexedDb-related types were added starting from TS 3 only. For example, `const storage: StorageManager = navigator.storage;` line wouldn't compile with TS 2.9, but would compile perfectly fine with TS 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `lib` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` to the list of lib files you want from TypeScript 2.9 (possibly an empty list) and then copy the `lib.*.d.ts` files you want from TypeScript 3.0 into your project, being sure to remove the `<reference>` directives so they don't accidentally pull in TypeScript 2.9 lib files.  Hopefully you can find a combination that works for you until Angular 7 is released with support for TypeScript 3.0.  If you run into specific issues that you can't solve, please update the question.